# Creation of the DC Extended Universe tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we don't currently have a tag designed to support the DCEU ([DC Extended Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe)) in the same way that we have a tag for the Marvel Cinematic Universe, so I created it.

[dc-extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe)

I've retagged all the current questions about *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice* in order to reflect this, but we currently have 42 questions tagged with [man-of-steel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/man-of-steel) that, in my eyes, should be retagged to also include [dc-extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe) thanks to the precedent (which I support) set by the way we use [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe).

What is the process for doing this, and should we do this?

Comment: 5-10 at a time, over several days in order to avoid swamping the front page.

Comment: Wasn't the *Justice League* movie canned? Does the DCEU even exist anymore?

Comment: @JasonBaker Unless that news has been made in the last hour or so, no, the upcoming two-part *Justice League* film has not been cancelled, and the DCEU still exists.

Comment: I don't think the man-of-steel tag should be retired, though. I think you can add the DCEU tag to any Man of Steel movie references.

Comment: This tag could also be used for Suicide Squad, which is set to release next year after *Dawn of Justice*

Comment: @DrRDizzle A'ight; I'm probably misremembering then

Comment: @Thaddeus Sorry if it reads that way, but I never intended to retire the *Man of Steel* tag.

Comment: @JasonBaker maybe you're thinking of the justice league dark project that del toro was attached to for a while

Comment: @phantom42 After some research, I'm pretty sure I was thinking of *Justice League Mortal*; some headlines about concept art from it came up in my news feeds a few months ago

Comment: You just want to be a Taxonomist, you wretched badge-whore ;-))

Comment: I wanna be a wretched badge-whore. Is there a Wretched Badge-Whore badge?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No, but there's a Wretched Rep-Whore badge; it's called [Legendary](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary).